# cUrl запрос в python

Tags: php, python, curl, get, request

есть код на PHP для GET запроса, нужно сделать такой же запрос в Python , никак не могу реализовать .

PHP:

```
$api_token = ''; // ваш идентификатор
$api_secret = ''; // ваш секретный ключ
$url = "https://api.freelancehunt.com/projects";
$method = "GET";
$signature = sign($api_secret, $url, $method);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $api_token . ":" . $signature,
CURLOPT_URL            => $url
]);
$return = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($return);
curl_close($curl);
```

sign функция уже есть реализованная на Python , нужен сам запрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализация с помощью [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

```
r = requests.get('https://api.freelancehunt.com/projects', auth=('api_token', 'signature'))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое